# Regular Expression beginning of line fault

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to simply match number between 90.000000 and -90.000000 with six float.
When I use this pattern:

```
^-?([0-9]|[1-8]\d|90)\.[0-9]{6}
```

The result:

```
-83.192292 => Match(True)
83.192292 => Match(True)
90.000000 => Match(True)
-0.000000 => Match(False)
-90.444444 => Match(False)
90.444444 => Match(False)
```

Comment: At least on Regex101 your regex seems to work just fine... https://regex101.com/r/QrW2Oj/1

Comment: But this give me error https://regex101.com/r/Vppa9D/1

Comment: You seem to forget about cases like 90.500000 or a plus sign in the beginning, btw.

Comment: You didn't select "multiline" from the settings. It assumes your regex matches the *whole* text then, not for each line separately.

Comment: Ok I see it thank you But this pattern also match -0.444444 How can I dismatch negative zero

Comment: That is not negative zero. It is a negative number between -1 and 0.

Comment: Also match  -90.191292 which is lower than -90.000000

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: you are right but also match -0.000000

Comment: You could use [`^(?!-0\.000000)-?(?:90\.000000|[1-8]?\d\.\d{6})`](https://regex101.com/r/Vppa9D/5), which excludes minus zero and numbers outside the range.

Comment: the result is your expect, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

[`^(?!-0\.000000)-?(?:90\.000000|[1-8]?\d\.\d{6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/Vppa9D/6)

It excludes minus zero (through negative look-ahead) and numbers outside the range (by checking for 90.0000 separately and then only allowing values for which the absolute integer part is < 90.

Make sure to use the `m` modifier when testing multiline texts. I also added the end-of-line anchor (`$`), in case you want to exclude matches when lines have more characters after the number (which could even be digits).